# Disabling replication in master is deleting records from slave automatically in SOLR 7.7

Tags: solr

We have 1 master and 2 slaves configuration. All servers are in sync with millions of documents. When i am disabling the replication from master server, the documents from slave servers are getting deleted automatically. In Master server documents are still there and i can search also. If any one faced such kind of issue in SOLR please help me. The same configuration in solr 4.7 is working fine.

master configuration:

```
   <lst name="master">
     <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
     <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
     <str name="confFiles">managed-schema,stopwords.txt</str>
   </lst>
```

Slave configuration:

```
<lst name="slave">
    <str name="masterUrl">https://example.com/solr/${solr.core.name}/replication</str>
    <str name="pollInterval">00:00:60</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: Same thing is happening solr 8.5. In solr 6.6 it is working fine, records are not getting deleted from slave, when disabling replication in master. Is there some more configuration we have to do, or it is a bug after solr 7.

Comment: This is one bug from solr 7 onwards. So take care while implementing disable replication in master slave architecture. You have to change the code in solr and rebuild solr.

Comment: could you share your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below java class and rebuild the solr.

solr-7.7.2\solr\core\src\java\org\apache\solr\handler\IndexFetcher.java

```
if (latestVersion == 0L) {
        if (forceReplication && commit.getGeneration() != 0) {
          // since we won't get the files for an empty index,
          // we just clear ours and commit
          log.info("New index in Master. Deleting mine...");
```

Here in 2nd if condition 'forceReplication' condition is not available after solr7. In solr 6 'forceReplication' is there. Add this condition and rebuild solr.

If you need more help you can comment.

---

There are some alternative solution also available. Depending upon your requirement you can choose. If you are disabling replication only because of after every commit to master you dont need a replication to happen, you can enable replication only after a optimize call instead of commit call. And from UI you can disable the enable/disable replication button.